# Find a nonzero $3\times 3$ matrix with all 0 eigenvalues. Is there a systematic way?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

After playing around for a bit I found one:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&0\\ 
0&0&1\\ 
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

but I couldn't find a good systematic way.

Comment: It is not hard to come up with non-zero *nilpotent* matrices.

Comment: I get lots of junk mail about solving nilpotency problems...

Comment: @AndréNicolas thank you for telling me what I was looking for! That+Wikipedia was a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All strictly triangular matrices are nilpotent [(*see here*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Strictly_triangular_matrix) & hence can have $0$ as the only eigenvalue.

Answer (score 3):

Let:

$$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0&a&c\\ 
0&0&b\\ 
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

with $ab \ne 0$ and $c$ arbitrary.

So the only eigenvalue is $\lambda_{1,2,3} = 0$, with multiplicity three.

**Update**: from CH's comment, the restriction on $a, b$ is not needed.

Comment: Why do you care about the values of $a,b$?

Comment: @copper.hat: You are correct, I don't need that restriction. Since $ab \ne 0$, the ﬁrst two rows are not proportional and their cross-product is $(ab, 0, 0)$, so the eigenspace, $E(0) = ker A$ is the line through $e_1 = (1, 0, 0)$. However, we don't need anything quite so rigid for this problem. I tried to do something to help match the example from the OP.

Comment: Nice post, and update, too...I've done my fare share of edits/updates based on feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Using the Schur decomposition, it is exactly 
the set of matrices $U T U^*$, where $U$ is unitary, and $T$ is strictly upper triangular.